# Can we have multiple dashboards of different dropdowns in python dash?

Tags: data-analysis, plotly-dash

Recently I started using dash for Data Visualization and I'm analyzing the Stock Data using qunadle API, but unable to get multiple dashboards of dropdown displaying the options of each dataset using a for loop like this

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import pandas as pd
import quandl
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import auth

api_key = auth.key

def easy_analysis(quandl_datasets):

    try:
        for dataset in quandl_datasets:
            df = quandl.get(dataset,authtoken=api_key)
            df = df.reset_index()

            app = dash.Dash(__name__)

            app.layout = html.Div([
                html.H3(dataset),
                dcc.Dropdown(
                        id=dataset,
                        options=[{'label' : s,'value' : s} for s in df.columns[1:]],
                        value=['Open'],
                        multi=True
                    ),
                dcc.Graph(id='dataset' + str(dataset))
            ])

            @app.callback(
                Output('dataset' + str(dataset),'figure'),
                [Input(dataset,'value')]
            )

            def draw_graph(dataset):
                graphs = []

                for column in dataset:
                    graphs.append(go.Scatter(
                        x=list(df.Date),
                        y=list(df[column]),
                        name=str(column),
                        mode='lines'
                    ))

                return {'data' : graphs}

        app.run_server(debug=True)

    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))


easy_analysis(['NSE/KOTAKNIFTY','NSE/ZENSARTECH','NSE/BSLGOLDETF'])
```

The Output which I expected was having multiple dashboards with all the dropdown options one after the other. But the result what I got was having only one dashboard of the last item in the easy_analysis() function list

```
easy_analysis(['NSE/KOTAKNIFTY','NSE/ZENSARTECH','NSE/BSLGOLDETF']), considered only 'NSE/BSLGOLDETF'
```

what am I supposed do to fix this and get multiple dashboards of each dataset as provided in the list. I also checked the Dash User Guide, but could not get what I was looking for.

But, when passed only one argument for only one dataset with a for loop, the code works fine and the graph changes according to the option selected in the dropdown.

[The code is here](https://github.com/chaotic-enigma/quandle_easy_analysis).

Answer (score 1):

The code does not work because you are redefining a Dash app at each iteration of the `for` loop.

Even if you have three datasets, you need to define the Dash app and its layout only once.

You can make three requests to the Quandl API and - if possible - save everything in the same pandas Dataframe.

One question is whether you want to display all dropdowns and graphs (i.e. dropdown + graph for each Quandl dataset) or only one dropdown and one graph. I would suggest to start with the first approach, because it's much easier. Anyway, for the second approach you can have a look at [this solution](https://community.plot.ly/t/callback-for-dynamically-created-graph/5511/4).